# Capitalize the first letter in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, capitalization

I have to capitalize the first character of a word without lowering any letters.
I've tried using `title()` and `capitalize()` but they change the whole word by lowering the capitalized letter(s).

```
word = "javaScript language"
```

I want the output to be JavaScript language.

Comment: I did check this question.. mine does not have an integer.

Comment: word[:1].upper() + word[1:]

Comment: @DSM fair enough - g4ur4v had an answer, but it seems both of ours are similar yet dissimilar enough that i'll include mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> word
'javaScript language'
>>> word[0].upper() + word[1:]
'JavaScript language'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant using slices the whole way

```
>>> word = "helloWorld"
>>> word
'helloWorld'
>>> word = word[:1].upper() + word[1:]
>>> word
'HelloWorld'
```

Per DSM's comment this version has better support for an empty string.  calling `[0]` on an empty string will result in an error.  Whereas `[:1]` and `[1:]` both return empty strings.

Comment: One advantage this has over `word[0]` is that it cleanly handles the empty string.